# Intermittent 401 unauthenticated issue while calling Google dataflow RestApi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

Have a requirement to spin up batch dataflows programmatically from a Streaming dataflow using the Google Rest API.
We have used Java implementation for this. 
The batch data flow will spin up when even ever a message is received by streaming dataflow. This works pretty fine for some time but at times we are getting **401 - unauthenticated error**. This is an intermittent issue ( like some times 15- 20 batch dataflows spins up, do its work and dies off. After 30 mins or so when it tries to spin up batch dataflow again, it throws 401 error)
Even i tried refreshing the token before getting the default token using below code snippet.

```
AccessToken access = ComputeEngineCredentials.getApplicationDefault().getAccessToken();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();

 HttpPost request =
    new HttpPost("https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/dataflow-begining/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://template/test.json");
 request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+access.getTokenValue());
 client.execute(request);
```

please help me to understand if i am doing anything wrong here. Or suggest if there is a better approach to this.

**Note:** we cannot use serviceaccount key to get the access token as the .json key is not available. And we dont have a clientId or client secret to send from our java program.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look to quotas ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Doesn't seems like a quota issue because when i try to spin up other Dataflow same time using "gcloud dataflow jobs run"   CLI command, it spins up perfectly.

Comment: You name your question as "intermittent" 401.But I understand that when you have a 401 error, you never success to create a new dataflow. Your program exit and you have to run a new one to restart the process, isn't it?

Comment: Yes i am spinning a batch dataflow from a streaming dataflow. So batch dataflow exit when there is an error. Again it tries to spin up another batch dataflow when streaming data flow when it receives a message in the pubsub